# Javascript array: How to check if two consecutive words are the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want my program to check if any two consecutive words in the array are the same. I believe that my "if" statement is correct, however the console.log shows that all consecutive words match. What am I miss here?

Any help appreciated! I'm new to this stuff :)

```
var wordArray = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "yellow"]

for (i=0; i<wordArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (i === i+1); {
        console.log("We have a match!");
    } //Why is this loop saying that all items in the array are equal?
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this. You were checking the index and not the element of the array, beside the wrong if statement.

```
for (i = 0; i < wordArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (wordArray[i] === wordArray[i + 1]) {
        console.log("We have a match!");
    }
}
```

Just a hint for better length handling, if the array is only one element long:

```
for (i = 1; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    if (wordArray[i - 1] === wordArray[i]) {
        console.log("We have a match!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var wordArray = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "yellow"]

for (i=1; i<wordArray.length; i++) {
    if (wordArray[i] === wordArray[i-1]) {
        console.log("We have a match!");
    }
}
```

Comment: watch the `;` after if

Comment: @NinaScholz yep I missed,

Comment: @Halcyon I testing with previous word so, it should go until last.

Comment: @Azzi ok, that works. Why did you decide to flip it around?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are actually comparing your index var "i" to "i + 1" in your code resulting in your console saying all items in the array are equal. 
Since you are actually comparing the index var , your Javascript is seeing this as :

```
if(1 === 2) 
    console.log("We have a match");
```

Since you actually want to compare the contents of wordArray :

```
if(wordArray[i] === wordArray[i + 1])
     console.log("We have a match!");
```

The important thing to remember here is that when using a "for" loop , the index variable ,"i" in this case, is only going to be an integer index for accessing the contents of the array.